# bad substitution ${line ::-1}

Tags: bash, substitution

i have this code and while it works perfect but i have an error in line `virusarray[i]=${line ::-1}`

> `testFile.sh: line 57: ${line ::-1}: bad substitution`

this kind of error. Everyone who knows?

```
declare -a virusarray
i=0

while read line; do  
  
#Reading each line by omitting backslash escape  
virusarray[i]=${line ::-1}
# echo $line
((i=i+1))
done < $virusfile
```

Comment: Why the `c` tag?

Comment: Try `${line::-1}`, I don't think bash likes that space

Comment: Specifically, the space is correct to use _before a number_ in fields inside your PE where there's ambiguity between numbers and operators (and both are valid); but this isn't one of those cases, and the space is simply wrong.

Comment: BTW, this is a very inefficient way to assign lines to an array. Considered `mapfile -t virusarray <"$virusfile"; virusarray=( "${virusarray[@]%?}" )`? Even `virusarray+=( "${line%?}" )` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it *is indeed* invalid syntax. Take out the space:

```
virusarray[i]=${line::-1}
```

...or even better, rewrite your loop entirely. Assuming you're using a bash release too old to support `mapfile` or `readarray`:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  virusarray+=( "${line%?}" )
done <virusfile
```

`${line%?}` serves the same purpose as `${line::-1}` (dropping the last character), but does so more portably, because it doesn't require bash-only extensions to shell syntax.